# Action of Lie group quotient

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I have a question, possibly silly, possibly already asked.

Imagine I have a Lie group $G$ such that $G$ quotient with its center, $Z(G)$ is a Lie group. (Bonus question: Is this not always the case and if so, is there a nice counterexample?).

If $G$ acts transitively on a manifold $M$, is it true $G/Z(G)$ inherits the action on $M$ and that it is also transitive?

If $G$ acts transitively on a sub-manifold (not subgroup!) $N \subset G$ by some action, does $G/Z(G)$ act transitively on $N/Z(G)$ by the "natural" inherited action?

Comment: $Z(G)$ is always a closed and normal subgroup, so $G/Z(G)$ is a Lie group. But why should it act on the same $M$? What if say $G$ is abelian?

Comment: Did you mean to ask if $G/Z(G)$ inherits an action on $M/Z(G)$? If so, then I believe so, although I'd write $Z(G)\backslash M$. And if the action is transitive, so too is the inherited action. Indeed, we ought to be able to say the same for any Lie subgroup, not just $Z(G)$, though we can worry about if the quotient is a manifold, when the action is topologically or geometrically nice, etc.

Comment: $G$ acts on itself by left translation., but why should $G/N$ acts ? For instance $SU(2)$ acts simply transitively on the unit 3-sphere of $C^2$, but $PSU(2)=SU(2)/\pm 1$ (which is homeomorphic to $RP^3$) do not.